# Two css columns. One dynamic, second fixed working together

Tags: css, dynamic, height, fixed, multiple-columns

I've got something similiar to two column layout.
 
Its width is 1000px.
 
There are two kind of objects.
 
Image object and text one.
I want them to look and behave like this(example image):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsKQp.jpg

But on my site its messed up, feel free to look at code:(please dont mind the language its polish, also image objects are grey rectangles)
http://uchman.org/pl/banan

what you are looking for on my site:

```
<ul class="miniatura">
 <li class="imag">      <-- image object
 </li>
 <li class="desc">      <-- text object
 </li>
</ul>
```

Problem

- when text object is higher than image object (>200px), the image object appears lower than it should, and page looks bad

Expectations

- text object has to have dynamic height of range 0-400px (i dont count margin
- image object should define grid like on my example image and text object should subject.
  For example if there is too much space between images, one image object should "jump" in place (on my site second image object is too low and there is ugly gap)
- gap after text object is fine (like on example image for eg if text object is 360px gap should be 40px)

I've tried some things and i cant find anything on the internet. I wont suggest what i have tried because i might done something wrong. The best solution would be pure html/css. I hope i described the problem well. Please help. :)

Comment: I followed your markup and your expectations. I did not understand everything, but why don't you try to make the mark-up like <div id="content"> <div class="column"> text and images goes here, each inside a div </div><!--/column--> <div class="column"> text and images for right column goes here too </div><!--/.column--> </div><!--/#content->

Comment: Hi, As far i understand this is exactly the same thing i have but Ive got list (ul, li) and you propose divs. Do you suggest the divs will behave differently? All i want is when wall of text is too high there will be two blocks of images and text wont make gaps between images. Now when text is too high the image blocks are too low.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what i understood from your description i did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanz/2NDsC/).

First time i guess this kind of mark-up will help you better

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="textBox">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem mollitia fugit voluptate expedita molestias optio deleniti ea nulla perspiciatis quae molestiae accusamus quisquam ab illum ipsam eos qui nam ad.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-490-200-7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-490-200-7.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-490-200-7.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="textBox">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem mollitia fugit voluptate expedita molestias optio deleniti ea nulla perspiciatis quae molestiae accusamus quisquam ab illum ipsam eos qui nam ad.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem mollitia fugit voluptate expedita molestias optio deleniti ea nulla perspiciatis quae molestiae accusamus quisquam ab illum ipsam eos qui nam ad.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/#container-->​
```

I also recommend to you to have a look over [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), it can be useful in some situations.

Comment: Your code is good but it has some minimum flaws. Masonry is what I needed! You're the man!

Comment: And this is how blocks behave with masonry after 1,5 hours of intensive thinking: http://i.imgur.com/PxSfg.jpg Thank You very much!